# View contents of mounted volume (temp folder)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have been running a program to retrieve removed contents of a very old hdd of mine. The program created a large temp folder in Appdata/Local/Temp, but when I open it it's empty despite being several hundred gb large. Is it possible to somehow view the contents?

The file ending of the folder is .tmp and it says that it's a mounted volume.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information.  What program were you using?  Are the files hidden?  Show us some screen shots? WHAT says that it is a mounted volume?  I (and others) would love to help you but this information would sure make it easier.

Comment: It's disk drill and windows says it's mounted when I right click on the folder and go to properties. There's no hidden files in it, I am showing hidden files by default. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Run a proper program to retrive the files. `scalpel` or `photorec` will do.

But there's probably an even less painful way to do it.

Comment: I have been running various free programs but disk drill is the only one able to retrieve the files I need

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows make sure that explorer shows hidden and system files.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a folder – a "mounted volume" is a pointer to *another partition,* similar to a drive letter. Use `diskmgmt.msc` or `mountvol` to determine what partition it's pointing to.

The size shown is the size of the entire partition (volume), not its contents, so a pointer to an empty 100GB partition will show up as 100GB in size. (The actual pointer only occupies a few hundred bytes on the original disk.)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! What do I do with it once I have found out which partition it's pointing to? I can't find it in the diskmgmt.msc. I see the harddrive (G) but that doesn't really help me view the contents

Comment: I also see these two but I can't be sure if it's them. (Disk 2 partition 3) and (Disk 3 partition 1)

Comment: Couldn't edit my previous posts. diskmgmt.msc says the last two are recovery partitions

Comment: Right-click each partition and use "Change drive letters or paths" to see all assignments including path-based mounts. (Though it might not necessarily be pointing to a regular partition, but e.g. to a shadow copy, but it's still worth a check.)